# Printing multiple strings from an array as a single string

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I want to print multiple Strings from an Array utilizing a for-loop, it will print a full first and last name, but only once. Here's my method for doing this.

This is the output I get:

"firstName secondName, "

There should be mutliple full names being printed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. The problem is you keep resetting `list` every time you iterate over `TANames`. Try this instead:

```
public String getTANames() {
    String list = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < TAList.length; i++){
        list += TAList[i].first + " " + TAList[i].second + ", ";
    }
    return list;
}
```

The difference is this line here: `list += TAList[i].first + " " + TAList[i].second + ", ";` you are adding to `list` not setting `list`.

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick! I was getting a little frustrated because I knew, for the most part, I had the right idea.

Comment: I wanted to immediately, but I had to wait a few minutes before doing so. Now it's time to alphabetize!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that in each iteration, you create a new memory location for ***list*** and so every time the loop executes, the value of ***list*** is **overwritten**. You can fix this by appending to list instead of changing the value of list in every iteration.

A side note, since Strings are immutable in java, for every iteration of the for loop, new memory will be allocated for ***list***. This is not very efficient. You should instead use StringBuilder which is mutable. It would look like this.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(list);
```

Then you can append to str :

```
str.append("any string");
```

This is equivalent to str + "any string"

Using StringBuilder, memory will be allocated to str only once and all the changes will take **in place** which is much more efficient. And finally you want to return a String object so you can call the method **toString()** on the StringBuilder object to convert it back into a String.

So, finally it would look like this :

```
public String getTANames() {
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("");
for(int i = 0; i < TAList.length; i++){
    str.append(TAList[i].first + " " + TAList[i].second + ", ");         
}
return str.toString();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, every loop changes the value of the **list** variable. To fix the issue, replace the current `=` with the `+=` as follows:

list **+=** TAList[i].first + " " + TAList[i].second + ", ";

```
public String getTANames() {
    String list = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < TAList.length; i++){
        list += TAList[i].first + " " + TAList[i].second + ", ";
    }
    return list;
}
```

Hope that helps.